# Specifying MutexSecurity for a named global mutex in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mutex

Is there a way to pass `MutexSecurity` to a `Mutex` in .NET Core (currently still using 2.2, switching to .NET 6 in the future)?

.NET Framework has a [constructor accepting this parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#system-threading-mutex-ctor(system-boolean-system-string-system-boolean@-system-security-accesscontrol-mutexsecurity)), but it seems to have been removed in .NET Core.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 6.0 there is the `MutexAcl` class:

```
#if NET6_0_OR_LATER
    using (var mutex = MutexAcl.Create(false, mutexId, out bool createdNew, securitySettings))
#else
    using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexId, out bool createdNew, securitySettings))
#endif
```

Which is available through the [System.Threading.AccessControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.AccessControl/6.0.0) nuget package.

The method will throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` if not on Windows (naturally).